# HibernateValidator is initializing Constraints when first evaluated, not at system load time

Tags: bean-validation

We are using HibernateValidator, and have the following issue:

We create our own validator object which implements ConstraintValidator. The first time the validator validates any specific Constraint, it calls the initialization code for that constraint. This is causing a performance problem. Is there any way that we can tell HibernateValidator to run the initialization for a Constraint at load time, not the first time the Constraint is actually validated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no such way. The spec basically just says:

> The life cycle of a constraint validation implementation instance is
>   undefined. Compliant implementations are allowed to cache
>   ConstraintValidator instances retrieved from the
>   ConstraintValidatorFactory. The initialize method is called by the
>   Bean validation provider prior to any use of the constraint
>   implementation.

It is only guaranteed that *initialize* is called prior a *isValid* call. There is no way to pre-initialize. The reason *initialize* is only called once is, because Validator caches the *ConstraintValidator* instance, but this is nothing I would rely on.

If you really want to make sure that *initialize* is called at startup you could do some warmup validation during this phase.

OOI, what are you doing in *initialize* that it becomes a performance issue?